# Redirect execution errors to file c++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, stdout, stderr

How can I redirect execution errors of a c++ executable in bash? I've found that 2> helps while trying identify compilation errors:

```
g++ example.cpp 2> compErr.txt
```

But running the executable with that command still sends the errors to stdout:

```
$ ./a.out 2> e.txt
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that this specific error message is written to stdout. Try `./a.out > e.txt`

Comment: That primiarily depends on what `example.cpp` implements on catching the exception. Can you show how that stuff is actually printed please?

Comment: It is actually a very simple sample code which I am using to experiment how to send its execution errors to a file:    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
 int a, b;
 a=3; b=0;
 cout << a/b << endl;
 return 0;

}

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie in this. I don't know how to format the code in the comment. But it is a simple division by zero. The error is not exactly the point, but the way of sending it to a file.

Comment: @nimrodm I tried your suggestion, but the error still appears in stdout and the e.txt remains empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something that worked in my terminal, here: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/822874-runtime-error-stderr-gcc-ubuntu-bash

In summary, a participant explained:

> In this particular case, the reason that the string "Floating point exception" is not >redirected is that it is not produced by the process that runs ./{file} or anything that it invokes. Instead,it is being produced by the command-interpreter itself.
>
> You can see this by telling the command interpreter to run another command interpreter, redirecting this sub-interpreter's error output. However, a bit of a >trick is required:

```
$ bash -c './{file}; true' >out 2>err    
$ cat out
$ cat err
bash: line 1: 28106 Floating point exception./test_fail
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the error "Floating point exception (core dumped)" does *not* come from the executable but from the shell! The messages from `bash` won't be suppressed by output redirection but there is a flag to enable/disable these messages.

You can install signal handlers for some of the errors which would cause the program to exit and write something to a suitable destination there. Some signals can't be intercepted and some other are hard to handle. That's the approach you can do from inside your code.

If you want to go further you *could* `fork()` your program first thing and have the actual work done in the child process. The parent process would essentially just `waitpid()` for the child process and use the information in the result structure received to report errors to a file.

Comment: Can you explain why would the shell output this message? (Except perhaps if the executable is invalid)

Comment: When the program exits with an exit code indicating that it probably received a signal which went unhandled and caused the program to exit, the shell prints these messages. The error message in this case simply says that some floating point operation in the program went bad (e.g., it resulted in a [signalling] NaN) and floating point exceptions are set to cause a signal.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect them to a file? I understand the problem, I actually induced the error in the .cpp. What I would like to know is how to send that error message to a file too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since in this situation I am just intending to compile and execute the code without "knowing" it,I would to know if there is a way to handle the execution errors directly with bash.

Comment: Thanks @DietmarKühl! I did something like that and it worked. I explain in depth what I found.